# Override compare list template in module

Tags: magento2, module

How to override template file

`Magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/template/product/compare/list.phtml` using module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the compare product listing template by using the below code in your module under `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_compare_index.xml`.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/compare/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Your `list.phtml` file is under `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/product/compare/list.phtml`

**Hope it helps!!!**

Answer (score 1):

First, override XML file `catalog_product_compare_index.xml`

> Filepath:Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.list">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vender_ModuleName::product/compare/list.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy Paste vendor file list.phtml file and change as per your requirement.